# Can't find Samsung Galaxy s4 obb folder for Expansion Files

Tags: android, development-environment, samsung-mobile, apk-expansion-files

I am not able to find the .obb folder on my Samsung Galaxy S4 on DDMS in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually asked this question so I could give an Answer for it. Basically what you want to do is..

1. DDMS Perspective in Eclipse.
2. File Explorer

Folder Path: /mnt/shell/emulated/obb/

Hope this helps!

joshysav